# Enter input of two digit in which first digit is column and second digit is row, the code should replace that place by X

Tags: python

Can some modifications in code 1 replace code 2?

code 1=(what is error in this and can this code work as same after correction?)

```
row1 = ["⬜️","⬜️","⬜️"]
row2 = ["⬜️","⬜️","⬜️"]
row3 = ["⬜️","⬜️","⬜️"]
map = [row1, row2, row3]
print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}")
position = (int(input("Where do you want to put the treasure? "))
if position==11:
  a=row1[0]="X"
elif position==12:
  row1[1]="X"
elif position==13:
  row1[2]="X"
elif position==21:
  row2[0]="X"
elif position==22:
  row2[1]="X"
elif position==23:
  row2[2]="X"
elif position==31:
  row3[0]="X"
elif position==32:
  row3[1]="X"
elif position==33:
  row3[2]="X"
```

code 2=

```
row1 = ["⬜️","⬜️","⬜️"]
row2 = ["⬜️","⬜️","⬜️"]
row3 = ["⬜️","⬜️","⬜️"]
map = [row1, row2, row3]
print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}")
position = input("Where do you want to put the treasure? ")
horizantal=int(position[0])#2
vertical=int(position[1])#3
map[vertical-1][horizantal-1]="X"
selected_row=map[vertical - 1 ]
selected_row[ horizanta l - 1 ]="X"

print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}")
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. I think the two codes are equivalent.

Comment: In code 2, you don't need to assign both `map[vertical-1][horizantal-1]` and `selected_row[ horizanta l - 1 ]`. They're both assigning the same thing.

Comment: In the second code, it considers only 2 digits. However, first considers the complete number.

Answer (score 0):

In the code 1 - a parenthesis is missing in this line:

```
position = (int(input("Where do you want to put the treasure? "))
```

Modify it to:

```
position = (int(input("Where do you want to put the treasure? ")))
```